# Laravel 4 - Cartalyst Sentry - No file or directory on database migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm currently trying to install Cartalyst - Sentry on my Laravel 4 framework.

My current composer.json consists of:

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "cartalyst/sentry": "2.0.*",
        "dflydev/markdown": "1.0.*@dev",
        "imagine/imagine": "0.6.*@dev",
        "twitter/bootstrap": "dev-calculate-it-son"
    },
```

I've added the service provider and alias for Sentry, as per these [instructions](http://docs.cartalyst.com/sentry-2/installation/laravel-4). I've also added the database details.

The final step, in Terminal, using this:

```
php artisan migrate --package=cartalyst/sentry
```

It brings up this error:

```
[PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

The package is installed in the vendor directory and the connection to the database is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

also make sure to pass the --env=local flag when running artisan calls in a local testing environment or artisan wont know what connection details to use.

of course 'local' can be any environment name.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Laravel nor Sentry problem, this probably is a PDO (database) connection error.

This is basic, but still: check if mysql is running and if mysqld.sock has the proper permissions.

Check if your php.ini file has it configured properly, example:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Verify the proper location of it by running:

```
mysqladmin variables
```

OR

```
mysqld --verbose --help | grep ^socket
```